# how to remove templateCache with gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angularjs-templates

i use angular-template-cache.
follow code exist for remove template cache in app module but i need to remove all templateCache with gulp on dev machine.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid template caching is revisioning your files.

Since you are using `gulp`, you can revision your files using `gulp-rev` or `gulp-rev-all`.

**What is revisioning?**

Static asset revisioning by appending content hash to filenames `unicorn.css` → `unicorn-d41d8cd98f.css`.

i.e., On every builds the filename changes and that way avoiding template caching.
You can revision every file including `.html`, `.css`, `.js`, `images`, `videos` etc.

Since `gulp-rev-all` is the latest and forked from `gulp-rev`, let's talk about `gulp-rev-all` only.

**Revisioning using `gulp-rev-all`:**

```
var revAll = require('gulp-rev-all');
```

if you want to neglect some files from revisioning, you can do that like this.

```
var rev = new revAll({dontRenameFile: [/^\/favicon.ico$/g, /^\/index.html/g]})
```

Consider all your files are in the folder `dist` and save the new revisioned files in the folder `www`.(You can save them in `dist` also. Considering `www` is your build directory.)

```
return gulp.src('dist/**')
  .pipe(rev.revision())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www'))
```

Next, create a `manifest` file to map your files with the revisioned one. for that use `.manifestFile()` function. which returns a transform function that will filter out any existing files going through the pipe and will emit a new manifest file. Must be called after .revision().

```
.pipe(rev.manifest())
.pipe(gulp.dest('www/manifest'));
```

An asset manifest, mapping the original paths to the revisioned paths, will be written to `www/manifest/rev-manifest.json`:

```
{
 "css/unicorn.css": "css/unicorn.098f6bcd.css",
 "js/unicorn.js": "js/unicorn.273c2cin.js"
 ..... 
 ..... 
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
gulp.task('rev', () => {
  var revAll = require('gulp-rev-all'),
    rev = new revAll({dontRenameFile: [/^\/favicon.ico$/g, /^\/index.html/g]});
return gulp.src('dist/**')
  .pipe(rev.revision())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www'))
  .pipe(rev.manifest())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www/manifest'));
});
```

Read more about `gulp-rev-all` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-all)

Comment: thanks for answering,but i use angular-template-cache for template caching,i want to removing templateCache with gulp on dev machine.